# Trouble running jar file created by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar

I exported my Eclipse project as a runnable Jar file, added a manifest, as well as the appropriate class files with the command:

```
jar cfm JarFile.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

However, when I try to run the jar file with

```
java -jar JarFile.jar
```

I get the error that it "Could not find or load main class" etc. etc.

The structure of my manifest.txt file looks like this:

```
Main-Class: EclipseProjectName.src.packagename.mainclassname
```

(With a carriage return at the end)

Is something wrong with my manifest file? If not, what may be the reason that the main class cannot be found?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The manifest file extension should be **.mf** i.e **manifest.mf**. See here for jar file [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JARManifest)

Suggest to use [fat jar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) eclipse plugin for exporting java projects as runnable jars.

#### Edit

Correct the content of **manifest.txt** as shown below

> Main-Class: <strike>EclipseProjectName.src.</strike>packagename.mainclassname

**project name and src are not required.** [Refer this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Comment: Using the m flag in the first command, I believe I am editing the .mf file with the .txt file.  I am pretty sure that I am editing the mf file correctly, because java recognizes the name of the main class, it just says that it could not find it.

Answer (score -1):

The entry in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry in the finished jar file should be

```
Main-Class: packagename.mainclassname
```

and should correspond exactly to

```
/packagename/mainclassname.class
```

in your jar file (or jar file_s_ if you use Class-Path too).

Comment: [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JARManifest). **Main-Class** attribute should not have **.class** extension.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK thank you for pointing out that I used "mainclassfile" instead of "mainclassname".  I did not, however, use the ".class" suffix so you may have been a bit hasty to downvote.